# Inconsistent body style, use expression body

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

I have this code:

```
private string _class;
public string Class
{
    get
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_class) ? "preview" : _class;
    }
    set
    {
        _class = value;
    }
}
```

How can this be simplified using expression body?

Comment: Or just don't use expression bodied members, they're evil...!

Comment: @Sean can you please elaborate why?

Comment: @Sean Just... no

Comment: ReSharper (which I assume you have as you have tagged it) will offer this refactoring for you to convert from statement body to expression body (or vice versa).

Comment: @DavidG and Guru-Stron Having 2 ways to right a method is needless. Plus you get developers writing overly complicated code just to make it fit into an expression rather than split it out into several expressions. It's a great example of how C# has lost its way.

Comment: @Sean Absolutely not true in my opinion. You may have a small point about devs writing complicated code to squeeze it in, but that's an education/best-practice thing. Having this feature allows us to cull boilerplate code, removing unnecessary lines from the file and making it much easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression bodies are [a new feature since C#7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members). If your getter or setter has only one line, you can simplify them with a syntax similar to lambda expressions to

```
public string Class
{
    get => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_class) ? "preview" : _class;
    set =>  _class = value;
}
```